# Adding bar labels with italics and superscript to a barplot

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, axis-labels, superscript

I am using `barplot` for my data.

I need to insert x-axis bar labels (sample names) which have superscripts and should be italicized. For instance, one of the sample names (bar labels) is *lab(delta21)*. Apart from the whole name to be in italics, I want the delta in (delta21) to be in symbol form and (delta21) to be a superscript of lab. (This is nothing fancy, just how biological gene mutant names are written).

I have tried fiddling around with `names.arg=expression()` but could not get it to work.

Any suggestions/ideas are most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this minimal example:

```
x <- rnorm(2)
barplot(x, names.arg = c(expression(paste(italic("1")^"st")), expression(paste(italic("2")^"nd"))))
```

`italic()` does the italic part, `^` does the superscript part.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use `ggplot2` to create your barplot because "bold, italic and bolditalic do not apply to symbols, and hence not to the Greek symbols such as mu" [quoted from this help page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html). I am also assuming that different numbers are assigned to different samples (e.g., Lab_delta21, Lab_delta22, etc).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

## make up data
data_table <- cast(mtcars, gear ~., value="mpg", mean)
data_table <- rename(data_table, c("(all)"="mean_mpg"))

lab_number <- 21:23
fancy_labels <- sapply(lab_number, function(x) paste0("italic(Lab[delta]", "[", x, "])"))
ggplot(data_table, aes(gear, mean_mpg)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 30))+
  geom_text(aes(label=fancy_labels), parse=TRUE, hjust=0.5, vjust=-0.5, size=7)
```

[image]

The second "[]" is necessary as in `[delta][21]` because without it `geom_text` recognize `[delta21]` as one word, without rendering `delta` into a Greek letter.